# Poor SVG quality compared to TIFF

Tags: r, graphics, svg

I have a filled.contour plot that I would like to save as SVG (or EPS) for publication. However I see that the quality of the SVG is significantly worse than that of the TIFF. The plot in the SVG file appears to have some kinds of white boxes/lines/rectangles which do not appear when I save the file in TIFF format. In the TIFF format the color transitions are much smoother and the white rectangles do not appear

Is there anyway to avoid this? I've tried Linux and Mac, getting similar results

Below is the TIFF file and a screenshot of the SVG file that shows the problem.

[image: TIFF]
[image: SVG screenshot]

The code to produce the plots is the following:

```
x <- 1:5
y <- 1:5
z <- matrix(outer(x,y,"+"),nrow=5)
filled.contour(x,y,z)
filled.contour(x,y,z,color.palette=rainbow)
z2 <- z
z2[5,5] <- Inf
filled.contour(x,y,z2,col=rainbow(100),nlevels=100)
```

Comment: You could add a simple `stroke-width: 0.5` and `stroke` with the same color as your `fill` so that the the white gaps are covered by strokes.

Comment: @Duopixel how do I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Believe it or not this is an anti-aliasing artifact.

http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Suppressing-internal-grid-in-filled-contour-td867081.html

On linux I can reproduce your problem, but when I pass the exact same file created in linux, into a windows OS virtual machine I have running - the SVG image appears fine, so it's a problem of the viewing software and anti-aliasing settings, not the R output.

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: WoW! Have to check with my own eyes! Which program can I used to open SVG files in Windows?

Comment: I can't seem to confirm this. Saved the file on linux in SVG and PDF format and opend them in WinXP (Firefox and Acrobat, respectively) and the artifacts remain (whitish grid lines)

Comment: According to [this link](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2009-February/187514.html) there should be an option in Acrobat to turn off anti-aliasing.

Comment: Same for me on Windows (and I am the author of the above quote). Even my standard trick, using cairoDev for better Anti-Aliasing, did not help

Comment: to ECII & @DieterMenne 
Try a simple SVG viewer like this one: [link](http://osspack32.googlecode.com/files/svgviewer.exe) (it's a standalone executable)

I see no white grid lines using this viewer.

Comment: @rmounce -- Nice find. Could you please link to the site from which you downloaded that, rather than directly to the executable?  Thanks.

Comment: [this is the site](https://code.google.com/p/osspack32/downloads/list)

although I actually found it by reading this page [here](http://opensourcepack.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/svg-viewer-for-windows.html) 

The trick it's its probably a very _simple_ SVG viewer. More complex programs that have anti-aliasing functions cause these apparent white grid lines AFAIK.

Comment: You can disable anti-aliasing in svg with `shape-rendering: crispEdges`

Comment: @Duopixel is this an option or a switch? Where can one disable this?

Comment: So, you guys think it would be OK to send the file for publication in SVG format, even though I see the lines?

Comment: OK. I can now confirm this. It is a viewer problem. The viewer suggested by @rmounce does not show the white gridlines.